# Isaacs FGT Problem 5B.1

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to solve Isaacs' Theory of Finite Groups problem 5B.1.
Let $G$ be finite and suppose that $P\in Syl_p(G)$ and that $g\in P$ has order $p$. If $g\in G'$, but $g\notin P'$, show that $g^t\in P'$ for some element $t\in G$ with $t\notin P$.

Following the indication, I have applied the transfer evaluation theorem: Let $v:G\rightarrow P/P'$ be the transfer map and $T$ a right transversal for $P$ in $G$. Then $$v(g)=P'\prod_{t\in T_0}tg^{n_t}t^{-1}$$ where $T_0\subset T$, $n_t|o(g)$, $\sum_{t\in T_0}n_t=[G:P]$ and $tg^{n_t}t^{-1}\in P$.
Since $o(g)=p, n_t=1$ or $p$. As $g^p=1$, it follows that $v(g)=P'\prod_{t\in T_0}tgt^{-1}$. Since $g\in G'$, $g\in\ker v$ and so $\prod_{t\in T_0}tgt^{-1}\in P'$.
Now I need to show that one of the $tgt^{-1}$ belongs to $P'$.

Comment: I think there is something wrong here. Let $G$ be the dihedral group of order $6$ and $P = \langle g \rangle \in {\rm Syl}_3(G)$. Then $g$ has order $3$ and $g \in G'$. But $p'=1$ so no conjugate of $g$ can be in $P'$.

Comment: Thanks very much Derek. Indeed, this example where $P$ is abelian shows that the question is wrong.

Comment: @DerekHolt Any guess as to what Isaacs could have possibly meant to ask here?

Comment: @the_fox I have only just noticed that the latest edition of the book has an "Errata" section on page 351, which says: It now read "that $g^t \in P'$ for some ...". Delete the dash on $P$. It should read "that $g^t \in P$ for some". I haven't thought about this corrected version.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah, many thanks! I had missed that there is now an errata section.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding an answer to the correct version of the problem for reference. I hope this argument is valid. So, to reiterate (using left notation):

> Let $G$ be finite and suppose that $P\in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$ and
> that $g\in P$ has order $p$. If $g\in G'$, but $g\notin P'$, show that
> ${}^t g \in P$ for some element $t\in G$ with $t\notin P$.

We work according to the hint and argue as follows. Let $v : G\rightarrow P/P'$ be the transfer homomorphism. Since $g \in G'$, we see that $g \in \ker(v)$. If $V$ is a pretransfer map relative to the left transversal $T$ for $P$ in $G$, then there is a subset $T_0$ of $T$ and positive integers $n_t$ such that $$V(g)=\prod_{t\in T_0}t^{-1}g^{n_t}t.$$ Since $g \in \ker(v)$, we see that $V(g) \in P'$.
Moreover, each $n_t$ divides the order of $g$ which is $p$. Now write $T_0$ as the disjoint union of $I$ and $J$, where $I$ and $J$ are such that $n_i = 1$ and $n_j = p$ for $i \in I$ and $j \in J$ (and only for those). At this point, observe that $|I| + p|J|$ is a $p'$-number, so $I$ is certainly non-empty. Then $$V(g) = \prod_{t\in I}t^{-1}gt.$$

Observe that for each $t \in I$ it is true that $t^{-1}gt \in P$. Now suppose that for each $t \in I$ we have $t \in P$. Since exactly one element of $T$ is in $P$ (owing to the fact that $T$ is a transversal for $P$ in $G$), we see that $I = \{t\}$ for some $t \in P$. But then $V(g) = t^{-1}gt \in P'$ and thus $g \in tP't^{-1} = P'$, where the equality is valid because $t \in P$ and $P' \unlhd P$. This conclusion contradicts the assumption $g \notin P'$. So it must be the case that for some $t \in I$ we have $t \notin P$ while simultaneously $t^{-1}gt \in P$. Taking $t^{-1}$ in place of $t$ completes the proof.